# Where is Sacagawea buried?

Tags: united-states, native-americans

Do we have a definitive answer as to where [Sacagawea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacagawea) (more [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/26683/who-is-the-latest-famous-person-to-have-no-known-likeness/26686#26686)) is buried? I followed the entire [Lewis and Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_and_Clark_Expedition) trail between 2003-2006 and was in no fewer than three or four towns/sites where she was reputedly buried.

Comment: Could you summarise who she was for the people who don't know?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Voting to close as too basic. Wikipedia makes it pretty clear that we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

> . . .  discovered a record of the pilot-woman's death in 1884 (when ninety-five years old) on the Shoshone Reservation, Wyoming, and her wind-swept grave."  *[Wikipedia:Sacagawea#burial_place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacagawea#Burial_place)* citing [Wood](https://%22The%20Lewis%20and%20Clark%20Expedition%22)

Although as P. Geerkens points out, there is considerable doubt.

Comment: I think he already read this and found it unreliable or needs another evidence or trail (as he links to the same wikipedia page)

Comment: Check the edit history. I provided the link in the question, then went back and read the page to find the answer.

Comment: OK. As we don't know for sure (and historians don't agree on a real year, 1812? 1884?), I thought the question was about some kind of "new" evidence.